# Random posts in WordPress change after page refresh

Tags: php, wordpress, session, posts

WordPress theme displays some random posts from a specific category.

I want to see the same posts everytime -- even after the page refresh.

How can I achieve this without making any changes to parent theme?

I think this has something to do with the user's session. Is this correct?

Comment: correct! without making any changes to theme I want to achieve this through user/visitor session.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a child theme. In child theme you can override change the way of posts are showing with using filters. Have a look on this. https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Comment: My question was "How can I achieve this without making any changes to parent theme. How I can do it through session?"

Comment: Thats what i am saying. Create a child theme of your parent theme and make changes into that. By this way you won't make any change in parent theme